# $.ajax() not working in any browser other than Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a small script which retrieves rental dates when the page loads, and also retrieves new dates if the user picks another month from the drop down.

The site is using jQuery 1.2.3 and I am stuck with that for now (legacy scripts) so I can't update to 1.4.

I wrote and debugged this in Firefox with Firebug, and realized that it doesn't work in any other browser. I am not sure why. In Firefox, I definitely get new dates and the div updates itself with the received AJAX data. Other browsers don't do anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/rental/get_dates.cfm',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'date=<cfoutput>#dateFormat(now(), "m-yyyy")#</cfoutput>&rental=<cfoutput>#val(getOneRental.rentalListingID)#</cfoutput>',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#rental_calendar .rentalRateData').html(data);
                }
            });

        });

        function update_calendar(date) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/rental/get_dates.cfm',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'date='+date+'&rental=<cfoutput>#val(getOneRental.rentalListingID)#</cfoutput>',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#rental_calendar .rentalRateData').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

HTML:

```
<form name="rental_month" id="rental_month" method="post">
    <select name="month">
        <cfset month_choice = dateFormat(now(), 'm-yyyy')>
        <cfoutput>
            <option value="#lcase(month_choice)#"  onclick="update_calendar('#month_choice#');" class="default">#dateFormat(month_choice, 'mmmm yyyy')#</option>
        </cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="i">
            <cfset month_choice = dateFormat(dateAdd('m', i, now()), 'm-yyyy')>

            <cfoutput>
                <option value="#lcase(month_choice)#" onclick="update_calendar('#month_choice#');">#dateFormat(month_choice, 'mmmm yyyy')#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
    </select>
</form>

    <div id="rental_calendar">
        <table class="rentalRates" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="98%">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Arrival</th>
                <th align="right">Rate</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="rentalRateData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="98%">  

        </table>
    </div>
```

Why does this only work in Firefox? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I believe it's possible to run multiple versions of jquery simultaneously.  You could encapsulate the code and load the latest version of jquery so that it is used just for your script.

Comment: I assume the `<cf*>` tags are not in the returned output, it is converted by then?

Comment: Coldfusion generates the option inputs. The HTML source would look like a regular HTML form.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I know that - do you have an example of the actual output received by the browser from the AJAX request.

Comment: @DKinzer: how do you do that?

Comment: @Kevin: You can run multiple versions of jQuery by using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Load the newer version first and assign it to a variable. Load the second version afterwards. That will ensure that all old scripts run without modifications. Your new scripts should use your variable.

Comment: The latest versions of Chrome and IE have decent enough console output. You should be able to pinpoint the exact error better than "it doesn't work in any other browser"

Comment: Chrome doesn't report any errors

Comment: Fixed, I think. I removed the onclick from the option, and instead made it onchange="update_calendar(this.value);" on the select element. Works in FF, Chrome, Safari. Checking IE.

Comment: Well, thats better. Doesn't work in IE7 now. Nothing is sent or returned. IE8 works fine.

Comment: Do you get back JSON? If you do, have you validated that the JSON is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet it's the html() function.  I'd try alerting the data to make sure the ajax functions are working, then try using a different way to add the data to your table.

Comment: I tried using .append, nothing happened. I put an alert() inside of update_calendar, and that did not fire either. I don't think it is being called.

Comment: that's really weird.  I would try even just alerting inside the document ready function to see if it may be something outside the ajax function.

Comment: Yeah. I moved the onclick to an onchange in the select element. Now it works, but not in IE7. IE7 gets the data back, but .html() has no effect. Also tried .append. It says 'Object does not support this property or method.'- same thing when I try using innerHTML.

Comment: You might not be able to use append on a table in IE.  I might try using a div instead of table for rentalRateData and adding the entire table inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the latest version of JQuery for your code. Here's an a link to an example of how to do this:

http://www.comanswer.com/question/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page